Flutter app does not able to restart background service automatically after stopped
I'm having a problem on flutter app im really so new on this framework and i need your help. Okay the task im trying to do is when there is alert send from the api, the app should provide notification alert. Now , i have done the fetching notication alert and all. Now i want to like add a snooze button on the notification, so that the user can stop the background alert fetching for a few minutes then it automatically restart the service.
The problem, im facing is that first the snooze button is not working on the notification, im not sure why and second problem is i am able to stop the service, but it does not restart back after the snooze period of time.
So, i made a screen with two button, one is trigger snooze which it should stop the service and restart it back automatically. It able to stop but does not restart it back.The second button is restart service, when i click it able to restart it.
Hope you guys can help me out with this problem.
Below are the code related to this:
background_service.dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:kms/main.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../../domain/entities/alert_entity.dart';
import 'alert_remote_data_source.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Timer? alertTimer;
Future<void> initializeService(String userId) async {
  
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  print('Starting background service...');
  //final AndroidNotificationSound? sound;

  // Ensure userId is saved in SharedPreferences
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setString('userId', userId);

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: false,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(), // Required, even if not using iOS
  );

  service.startService();
  print('Background service started. Invoking userId: $userId');
  service.invoke('setUserId', {'userId': userId});
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  String? userId;
  Timer? alertTimer;
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  print('Service onStart called.');
  userId = prefs.getString('userId');
  print(userId != null
      ? 'UserId retrieved from SharedPreferences: $userId'
      : 'No userId found in SharedPreferences.');

  // Listening for service events
  service.on('setUserId').listen((data) async {
    userId = data?['userId'];
    if (userId != null) {
      await prefs.setString('userId', userId!);
      print('UserId updated in SharedPreferences: $userId');
    }
  });

  service.on('snooze').listen((data) async {
    print('Snooze action received.');

    // Cancel any ongoing timer
    alertTimer?.cancel();
    alertTimer = null;
    print('Alert timer canceled.');

    // Stop the service
    service.stopSelf();
    print('Service stopped for snooze.');

    // Restart the service after the snooze duration
    const snoozeDuration = Duration(seconds: 10);
    Future.delayed(snoozeDuration, () async {
      print('Attempting to restart the service after snooze delay...');
      final restarted = await FlutterBackgroundService().startService();
      print(restarted
          ? 'Service restarted successfully.'
          : 'Failed to restart the service.');
    });
  });

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    print('StopService action received.');
    alertTimer?.cancel();
    alertTimer = null;
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
      title: "Service Running",
      content: "Monitoring alerts in the background.",
    );
    print('Foreground notification configured.');

    // Wait for userId if not yet available
    while (userId == null) {
      print('Waiting for userId...');
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      userId = prefs.getString('userId');
    }

    // Set up the alert timer to perform periodic tasks
    alertTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 60), (timer) async {
      if (userId != null) {
        print('Timer triggered for userId: $userId');
        await checkForAlerts(userId!);
      }
    });
  }
}




void stopFetchingAlerts(ServiceInstance service, {required Duration snoozeDuration}) async {
  print('Snooze activated for $snoozeDuration.');
  
  // Cancel the ongoing timer
  alertTimer?.cancel();
  alertTimer = null;
  print('Timer canceled.');

  // Stop the service
  service.stopSelf();
  print('Service stopped for snooze.');

  // Use a delayed Future to restart the service
  Future.delayed(snoozeDuration, () async {
    print('Attempting to restart service after snooze...');

    final restartedService = FlutterBackgroundService();
    bool isStarted = await restartedService.startService();
    
    if (isStarted) {
      print('Service restarted successfully after snooze.');

      // Restart the timer for alerts
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String? userId = prefs.getString('userId');

      if (userId != null) {
        alertTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 60), (timer) async {
          print('Timer triggered for userId: $userId');
          await checkForAlerts(userId);
        });
        print('Timer restarted after snooze.');
      } else {
        print('Failed to retrieve userId after restarting service.');
      }
    } else {
      print('Failed to restart service after snooze.');
    }
  });
}


// Periodically check for new alerts and show notification
Future<void> checkForAlerts(String userId) async {
  // print('Checking for alerts for userId: $userId');
  //print('checkForAlerts called');
  final alertRemoteDataSource = AlertRemoteDataSource(http.Client());

  // Replace with actual userId and isPersonalFarm parameters
  //const String userId = '7251424466327183360'; // Replace with real user ID
  //const bool isPersonalFarm = true; // Set based on requirement

  try {
    final alerts = await alertRemoteDataSource.fetchAlertData(userId, true);
    print('Fetched ${alerts.length} alerts');

    // Send notification if there are any alerts
    for (AlertEntity alert in alerts) {
      print('Processing alert: ${alert.farmName}');
      sendNotification(alert);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error fetching alerts: $error');
  }
}

Future<void> sendNotification(AlertEntity alert) async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'alert_channel', // ID of the notification channel
    'Alerts',
    importance: Importance.high,
    priority: Priority.high,
    icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher', // Ensure this exists
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('alert_sound'),
    playSound: true,
    actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
      AndroidNotificationAction(
        'SNOOZE_ACTION', // Unique identifier for the action
        'Snooze', // Label for the action
      ),
    ],
  );

  const NotificationDetails platformDetails = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidDetails,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, // Notification ID
    'Alert : ${alert.farmName}',
    '${alert.pondName}: ${alert.alert}',

    platformDetails,
  );
  print('Sending notification for alert: ${alert.farmName}');
}

main.dart
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize notification channel and check permissions
  await setupNotificationChannel();
  await checkNotificationPermission();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final httpClient = http.Client();

    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => AuthCubit(
              AuthRepository(
                AuthRemoteDataSource(),
              ),
            )..checkLoginStatus(),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => PersonalFarmCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => PersonalFarmHistoryCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => RegisterCubit(
              RegisterRepository(
                RegisterRemoteDataSource(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => CommunityFarmCubit(
              CommunityFarmRepository(CommunityFarmRemoteDataSource()),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => CommunityFarmHistoryCubit(
              CommunityFarmRepositoryHistory(
                  CommunityFarmRemoteDataSourceHistory()),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => AlertCubit(
              GetAlertsUseCase(
                AlertRepositoryImpl(
                  AlertRemoteDataSource(httpClient),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => ProfileCubit(
              UpdateProfileUseCase(
                ProfileRepositoryImpl(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => PasswordCubit(
              ChangePasswordUseCase(
                PasswordRepositoryImpl(httpClient),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                AquaFarmCubit(AquaFarmRepositoryImpl(http.Client())),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => PondCubit(PondRepositoryImpl(http.Client())),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                SensorCubit(SensorRepositoryImpl(http.Client())),
          ),
        ],
        child: BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
          listener: (context, state) async {
            if (state.isLoggedIn && state.userId != null) {
              print("Starting service with userId: ${state.userId}");
              await initializeService(state.userId!);
            }
          },
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return state.isLoggedIn ? AlertMyPage() : LoginScreen();
              },
            ),
            routes: {
              '/login': (context) => const LoginScreen(),
              '/register': (context) => const RegisterScreen(),
              '/alert': (context) => AlertMyPage(),
              '/settings': (context) => SettingsPage(),
              '/settings_registration': (context) => SettingsRegistrationPage(),
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

Future<void> setupNotificationChannel() async {
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'alert_channel',
    'Alerts',
    description: 'This channel is used for alert notifications.',
    importance: Importance.high,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('alert_sound'),
    playSound: true,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
    ),
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
      if (response.actionId == 'SNOOZE_ACTION') {
        print("Snooze action clicked!");
        FlutterBackgroundService().invoke('snooze'); // Trigger snooze action
      }
    },
  );
}

Future<void> checkNotificationPermission() async {
  if (await Permission.notification.isDenied) {
    await Permission.notification.request();
  }
}

test_snooze.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';

class TestSnoozeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestSnoozeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test Snooze Functionality'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Trigger the snooze event
                print('Snooze button clicked');
                FlutterBackgroundService().invoke('snooze', {});
              },
              child: const Text('Trigger Snooze'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20), // Add spacing between buttons
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // Restart the service manually
                print('Restart button clicked');
                final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
                bool isRunning = await service.isRunning();
                if (!isRunning) {
                  await service.startService();
                  print('Service restarted manually');
                } else {
                  print('Service is already running');
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Restart Service'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

